# Content of widgets keep disappearing over and over again

Tags: widgets

Alright guys this might sound like a strange issue but I'll try to be as clear as possible.

So we've had a website which was running **Flatsome 2.x**
But some while ago Flatsome did a major update, and now they're on **3.5**. So we've took out a day to update the Theme & all the plugins on the website because we knew there would be alot to adapt to.

Everything went fairly smooth and we managed to get through. But now all of a sudden our widgets keep disappearing, we have about 3 widgets that we use as sidebars.

- One in the woocommerce shop
- One for the footer
- and the last one on another page that has some content blocks in it.

Now we've encountered everything.
Somtimes when I'm readding every element to the widget, and I save, the ones I previous did just disappear. Then all of a sudden, all of the blocks I need are back.

After a while we managed to get them all back, so we quit working on that website. Few hours later, we go check, the sidebars are empty again.

To be clear, in the meanwhile of the widgets disappearing, none of us was in the admin area of the website.
I don't really believe in ghosts or leprechauns, but I might rethink my religion here :P

I'm just wondering if any of you guys here already encountered this problem or has any solution? I will be most grateful. Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds pretty theme-specific so I would suggest contacting the theme support team directly.

Comment: I am experiencing this same thing. Right after I add widgets to the sidebar and then save. After I save, I leave the admin area to look to see if the widgets are appearing in the sidebar. They are there when I look, but then when I go back to the admin area, they disappear. But only to the new ones I'm trying to add. The preexisting widgets aren't disappearing.

Comment: Do you have the plugin Yoast SEO enabled?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing.  Were you able to solve this?

Comment: We had our hosting provider disable VARNISH caching, this was causing the issue.